# core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'translate' could not be found

Tags: angular

core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'translate' could not be found
when i use translat in componnent.html it will work
This is my index componenet inside one folder

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, AfterViewInit, Input } from 
'@angular/core';
import { Helpers } from '../../helpers';
import { ScriptLoaderService } from '../../_services/script-loader.service';
import {TranslateService , TranslatePipe } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
selector: "app-index",
templateUrl: "./index.component.html",
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

@Input() isLogin: number | string;

constructor(private _script: ScriptLoaderService ,private translate: 
TranslateService) {
translate.addLangs(['en', 'fr']);
translate.setDefaultLang('en');
translate.use('en');
}
ngOnInit() {

}
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._script.loadScripts('app-index',
        ['assets/app/js/dashboard.js']);

}
```

}

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: here is my code

Comment: Are you importing the module correctly in your app.module?

Comment: Check the module is imported. This is the full documentation
https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#1-import-the-translatemodule